# "Explain" versus "Explicate"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Is there a difference in meaning between the words '***explain***' and '***explicate***', or are they interchangeable?

It seems that *explicate* is just a very formal (pretentious?) version of *explain*, that is used in philosophical and artistic contexts. Every time I've seen the word *explicate* used, it could be replaced by *explain* with no loss of clarity.

Comment: Explicate I find is used more in a scientific context and it is quite formal. In everyday use, however, 'explain' would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Dimitri So you would say they have the same meaning, just expressed in different registers?

Comment: Well context is important in this case and not to mention formality. In any case, you may use explain for any purpose, whether be it scientific, philosophical or something as simple as using stove! Don't over-think it too much! :)

Comment: Just an observation. All words have distinct meanings (often of slight nuances), otherwise there would be no need for them. Often, years of time, or differing cultures, etc., obliterate the differences. But, if one were around in the initial formulation of the word, the differences would be clear. Latin also has this same distinction. These differing words are often generated in a different context. Then there are those words that remain the same in spelling, but have different meanings.

Comment: There is nothing pretentious or formal about *explicate* or using *explicate*.

Comment: It's a matter of frequency.Longman's DCE indicates that to explain is a frequent verb of the basic vocabulary. But you have to read a lot till you find the academic verb to explicate. It does not belong to the frequently used words according to Longman.

Comment: I think you're right. They can be used interchangeably. I think it's useful to say explicate when you want to expand the vocabulary of your audience or you want to show people that you have an expansive vocabulary. Sometimes the use of such language may be seen as grandiloquent, however it can also inspire others to also expand their vocabulary. If you are a member of an opressed group, it can showcase that members of your group are capable of using sophisticated verbiage. Its important to do such things in moderation and remain humble.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental difference between *explain* and *explicate* is the presence of the 'person' in the first case.

Simpler things first:

> You explain it **to someone**.
>   You explicate it.

Google Web definitions:

> **explain** *verb*
>   1. make (an idea, situation, or problem) clear to someone by describing it in more detail or revealing relevant facts or ideas. "they explained that their lives centered on the religious rituals"
>
> **explicate** *verb*
>   1. analyze and develop (an idea or principle) in detail. "attempting to explicate the relationship between crime and economic forces"

An 'explanation' is essentially tailored to the listener/ reader's need to understand, while an 'explication' is a mere setting forth of the finer details.

The words can be and, are indeed sometimes, used interchangeably. You can just explain something (with no explicit 'other person'), and you can explicate to someone.

---

[ChicagoBusiness, Nov. 04](http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/20131102/ISSUE03/311029989/pullman-inching-closer-to-national-park-status)

> … the National Park Service has concluded Pullman is nationally significant in that it **explicates** industrial, labor and African-American history in ways not represented at other national park sites. ()

[Inquirer, Nov. 02](http://newsinfo.inquirer.net/518829/pork-barrel-issue-far-from-dead)

> … Palace mouthpieces yesterday continued to **explicate** on the theme of the President and the pork barrel, …

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Other dictionaries (e.g. thefreedictionary.com) define explain as "To make plain or comprehensible." Further, in common usage, it doesn't seem like there needs to be a target. A professor could explain a poem to an empty room, and I'm sure I've heard of books explaining things (with no particular recipient indicated).

Comment: I see you that mention this in your answer. But it seems you simply retracting what you just said, which leaves me confused. Are you or are you not claiming a distinction?

Comment: @Potato You did use the infinitive, didn't you :) "explain a poem **to** an empty room"! Books, of course, *explain* because they have a target audience by default; you don't write a book for no one to read it. As I said, the distinction does exist, though it is not widely-recognized, which is the reason for this question in the first place -- doesn't that sound but natural?

Comment: You mixed up a couple of things, IMO. +1 for a possible difference in level of detail and analysis (possible, because an explanation **can** also be detailed and precise). -1 for saying that one targets a person and is sensitive to audience understanding and background, while the other "*is a mere setting forth of the finer details*". I don't agree with the latter claim.

Comment: @Drew Those words earning your -1 essentially say the same thing as the "**explain** *verb* **1.** " entry cited above. :)

Comment: Your self-identified main point (*the fundamental difference*) was that *explain* speaks to a person, with the explanation tailored to the audience, while *explicate* does not. I disagree with that completely. Not only is this not *the fundamental difference*, it is not even ***a*** difference.

Answer (score 1):

Well people, with words like these - explain vs explicate - you have to go "OG" and pull out the old Oxford English Dictionary for the LATIN and/or OLD ENGLISH origin.  With EXPLAIN you have the Latin origin 'planus', or 'plain'.  Now we need to infer; to explain means to make something complicated plain or understandable.  We are literally 'taking out' (thus the 'ex')the plain or uncomplicated part of what is being discussed. With EXPLICATE, we have the Latin origin 'plicare', or 'to fold'.  Thus we are 'taking out' the folds of what is being discussed.  I, therefore, would explain a basketball play (pick and roll), and would explicate a poem.  It should be noted that explicate is word associated with literature in common speech.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, they are different.

***Explicate*** will often be used when you are explaining something complex or philosophically deep.

It's true when you said that you would use **explicate** in academics, politics, finance, philosophic context and stuff. It indicates a very detailed explanation (including reasons why things are the way they are), and it is sometimes a complex one.

> "He explicated the nature of political economy on foreign central governments."

---

***Explain*** can be used for that same purpose or more common purposes, such as explaining instructions or very basic academic ideas. This may **not** include deep thinking and understanding of reasons behind ideas.

> "He explained how to use the grill."

Also, I don't think **explicate** is a *very* formal form of **explain** though. You can use **explain** in formal writings too.

Comment: So you would say 'explicated' is the same as 'gave a detailed explanation'?

Comment: Yea, indeed. That's why, perhaps, *explicate* is not often used in daily English.

Comment: First time I have seen it in my many, many years of reading everyday English so it must be a word used in Science

Comment: @mplungjan: Yeah that's true. *Explicate* is not really used by "normal" people.

Comment: @Safira There are lots of people who are not 'normal' by your definition (~1,310,000 instances of usage).

Comment: I was kidding, @Kris..

Answer (score -1):

To me, *explicate* has more of a connotation of *develop* or *elaborate*, that is, to explain in detail. You can give a summary explanation of something, but an explication gets into the nitty gritty and is typically precise.

And [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=explicate) gives *develop* and *formulate* as synonyms for *explicate*, but not for *explain* (for which the only synonyms it gives are *excuse* and *explicate*).

Comment: Care to explain why the downvote?

Answer (score -3):

One dictionary has "explicate" tagged with "formal".    Another place adds that to "explicate" has the sense of going into greater detail than "explain".

Comment: Which dictionaries?